# EC2 AWS Instance: Check if tomcat is running

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I'm using amazon EC2 instances to run tomcat servers.

I do this with java. I know how to start up an instance dynamically but the problem is that I have to wait to make webservice calls (the instances run a tomcat server which run an project with http services) till AFTER tomcat is running.

Is there a way to request the Tomcat running state at the ec2 instance?

So my java project created a new EC2 instances with a certain AMI.
I wait till that instance is booted and get the public DNS.
Then I want to do some webservice calls to that EC2 instance. The problem is that I get a connection refused error if I request too fast and tomcat isn't running yet.

Comment: Is there a way perhaps to check if certain ports are open? Like in this case the :80 or :8080? Or isn't that sufficient to know that tomcat is up?

Comment: PS: I solved it by simply waiting 10 minutes after tomcat startup. Far from ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with bleeding some of your application management to provisioning side, you can log into the instance from the EC2 provision code to check for tomcat process. This would be well synchronized with provisioning step as you can wait on instance status until it becomes running and gets public DNS.

Comment: That might be a solution but sounds very tedious and a lot of ways that it might fail. Isn't there an easier way like scanning the status of certain ports or something?